# Should I format my external hard disks in EXT4 or NTFS or BTRFS?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ntfs, ext4, btrfs

I have four hard disks:

- 240GB SSD formatted as EXT4 for main OS.
- 3TB HDD formatted as NTFS for main files.
- 500GB HDD formatted as NTFS for luks containers.
- 4TB HDD formatted as NTFS for backuping all other three hard disks.

I am getting too *many* input/output errors with my 3TB HDD NTFS hard disk for main files.

I was using NTFS due to compatibility.

But, I've never used them on Windows, only on Fedora Linux.

Should I keep with NTFS? Or should I reformat all them to EXT4 or BTRFS?

Will these input/output errors end with EXT4 or BTRFS?

Comment: You say, “I was using NTFS due to compatibility.” but then you say, “But, I've never used them on Windows, only on Fedora Linux.” So did you format it as NTFS for the idea/concept of compatibility? Then you never ended up using the NTFS drive on Windows? Unsure if EXT4 will save you from errors, but honestly if you don’t need NTFS then don’t use NTFS. You are just adding a layer of complexity that is not needed.

Comment: NTFS is just for safety. If I need to open it on windows, for backuping, for reading, for fixing, anything. But, in 8 years, I never needed it. I never tought about difficults for linux handling ntfs partitions, so NTFS was my first choice due compatibility. :-(

Comment: Why are you posting what is effectively the [same exact question again here](https://superuser.com/q/1614361/167207)?

Answer (score -1):

I've been down this same route over many years. I have a 4TB drive that I had formatted as NTFS that was attached to a linux server running as a samba server on my network and have had persistent issues over the years. Particularly when linux permissions get corrupted as NTFS isn't a native linux format and is actually proprietary Microsoft [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS], the translation has to interpret the differences in permissions of linux and permissions on NTFS, and doesn't always get them correct. I recently (2 years ago) changed my 4TB external to ext4 and haven't had any real issues since then. I also have a backup of that drive which I have recently converted from ext4 to btrfs after some research and have been quite happy with that format.

Comment: Nice to hear, thank you. Do you keep your 4TB external as NTFS ? Should I reformat all my disks and containerts to btrfs too ? Or should I reformat all them to ext4 and only backup disk to btrfs ?

Answer (score -2):

Focusing only on the 3Tb drive.  Because of the "I am getting too many input/output errors" I would recommend running the manufacturers hard drive diagnostics against the 3Tb drive to make sure that the drive is still healthy.  A nice collection of them can be found on Hiren's Boot Disks under the Dos Programs / Hard drive tools.  Western Digital and Seagate are on page 2, HGST is on page 3.  Use the HGST to test any drive not WD or Seagate.  This will rule out hardware.

However, if you aren't having a problem with NTFS on the other two drives it probably isn't the file structure.

Comment: I am focused on a probable complete restructuring. I've already had same problems of input/output error inside luks containers formatted as NTFS too. :-(

Comment: Based on your question about a single drive with errors, my recommendation is to test the hardware because IF the drive is failing, it won't matter what file structure you put on it.

Comment: I've already performed a chkdsk /f, I can remove some orphan files, that I can't remove only with linux. But, others files with input/output erros can't be fixed. They keep with errors, but isolated. All others files keep working perfectly. Should i perform any other test?